# Java Unix set property

Tags: java, unix

In the java, I have a code like this:

```
 String home = System.getProperty("project.home");
```

In the unix, how can I set a value to variable "project.home" ? for example, my project default dir should be "/apps/myproject".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either set it when invoking your JRE, for example:

`java -Dproject.home=/apps/myproject`

or you can do so programmatically:

`System.setProperty("project.home", "/apps/myproject");`

Answer (score 1):

[System.setProperty](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will do the job for you.